# Docker containers can't communicate between them when flask api is served with uwsgi

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, microservices, uwsgi

I have as example two microservices running in two docker containers created with flask and served with uwsgi to a **nginx proxy**. Docker-compose file it's looking something like this:

```
nginx:
  build: ...
  container_name: ...
  restart: always
  hostname: my-host
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  expose:
    - 80
  networks:
    - my-net

micro1:
  build: ...
  container_name: ...
  restart: always
  hostname: my-host
  expose:
    - 8080
  networks:
    - my-net

micro2:
  build: ...
  container_name: ...
  restart: always
  hostname: my-host
  expose:
    - 8081
  networks:
    - my-net
```

and my `.ini` file something like this

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = micro1.py
callable = micro1_api
socket = :8080
...
```

Now my problem is that I can't communicate between them. If I try to make a normal request with `requests` as example, I get an error with following message on docker container log:

```
invalid request block size: (max 4096)...skip uwsgi
```

I've increased `buffer-size`, but then another error (I think...) appears on console:

```
uwsgi_proto_uwsgi_parser(): Success [proto/uwsgi.c line 40]
```

with a timeout when making request.

Can't switch protocol since nginx is configured as `uwsgi_pass micro1_upstream` and changing protocol to http, nginx won't serve my requests, but calling containers inside will work. Also tried to use sockets, but no luck.

In this case, how can I communicate between containers?

Comment: How are you actually trying to call between the containers; what does the actual `requests.get()` call look like?  Are your containers actually serving HTTP or the separate [uwsgi wire protocol](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Protocol.html)?

Comment: @DavidMaze request is made using container name: `requests.get("http://micro2:8081/", timeout=10)` and they are served using wire protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uWSGI has a [custom wire protocol](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Protocol.html) that has some advantages over the traditional text-based HTTP/1 protocol.  Your configuration and error messages indicate that the listener is expecting this protocol, and your Nginx configuration presumably has a matching `uwsgi_pass` directive.  However, the Python `requests` module expects to speak ordinary HTTP, not this custom protocol.

That is: you're correctly making the connection between containers – you are not getting a DNS error or "connection refused", bits are flowing across the virtual wire – but the client is speaking HTTP and the server is expecting the uwsgi protocol.  That mismatch leads to the errors you see on both sides.

uWSGI can also provide a [normal HTTP server](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTP.html).  You should be able to configure uWSGI to run both the native wire protocol and also standard HTTP:

```ini
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = micro1.py
callable = micro1_api
uwsgi-socket = :8080
http-socket = :9090
```

The Nginx configuration can use `uwsgi_pass micro1:8080`, but standard HTTP clients like `requests` need to use the HTTP port, `http://micro1:9090`.

You do not need any changes in your Docker configuration to use this.  The existing `expose:` blocks do essentially nothing and it's safe to remove them.  (Similarly you should be able to delete `hostname:`, `container_name:`, and all of the `networks:` blocks in the file without actually affecting anything.)

Comment: Thank you!! You just saved me after a week of wrong answers.`http-socket` option did the trick in my case.

Comment: if I remove `network` blocks containers should be able to communicate to each other? What if I have a database? (mongo, rabbitmq, etc)

Comment: Compose automatically creates a network named `default` and attaches containers to it; you don't have to set this up by hand.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has more details.